# vectorize raster image containing lines

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

I would like to vectorize a PNG containing lines (DN=1 for line, DN=0 for transparent background). See below. As the data is georeferenced I'm asking it here. I would like to automate the vectorization and I'm currently looking into Python/GDAL/QGIS solutions with a vector result in the form of a shapefile. I found gdal_polygonize but this tools creates a polygon shapefile while I would like to create polylines. Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

**UPDATE:** Searching for an open source solution, so without using ArcGIS like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139911/vectorizing-from-raster-image-with-discontinuities-or-breaks-in-polygons) solution.

[image]

Comment: Suggested approach in the linked answer was r.to.vect but as you already have polygon **Vector | Geometry Tools | Polygons to Lines** can also be useful.

Comment: Polygons to Lines creates lines of the polygon borders so that's not what I'm after unfortunately.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention r.to.vect, my bad. I will try it out, and an other option may be found in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713821/my-implementation-of-bresenhams-algorithm-fails-for-lines-at-certain-angles